# How do I show a (calendar like) list of all days in a month, some are empty, others have (1 or multiple) events, without using 31 gridviews?

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I need to display a calendar-like list of events. Basically, I want to show a table with 31 rows (depending on the month, of course, but that's not the difficult part), with in the first column all dates from 1 to 31. In the second column, I want to show the records that are planned on that specific dates. This can be one record, multiple records or no records (and then I still want to show this empty cell, with a button like 'Create new event here).

The shown records should allow me to do stuff like edit fields to each of the records, so I was planning on using a gridview for that.

I am a bit puzzled what the best approach would be, performance-wise. I can for instance create a repeater that shows the 31 days, with a gridview nested in it which uses a datasource to get the records corresponding with the day. This seems not the best way, because the datasource then has to fetch records from the database 31 times and I end up with 31 gridviews on my page.

Is there a way to grab all the records in the code-behind, and then dynamically create the whole table including the gridviews, whilst still showing the 'empty days'?

Answer (score 0):

```
How To Conditionally Disable Dates In Calendar Control?
```

Standard Calendar control is very useful and has its important place on Visual Studio toolbox. Very often, developers need to allow only specific time ranges and disable others. For example, if your web application need to save hotel reservation then it will accept only future dates. Otherwise, if you want for example to search archive posts in blog application then application will allow only past dates to be selected.

All dates in Calendar control are enabled by default. To disable certain dates, you need to use DayRender event, you can do it with code like this:

[ C# ]

// We need this namespace
using System.Drawing;

public partial class DefaultCS : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs e)
  {

```
// Select all dates in the past
if (e.Day.Date < System.DateTime.Today)
{   

  // Disable date
  e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
  // Change color of disabled date
  e.Cell.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
}
```

}
}

[ VB.NET ]

' We need this namespace
Imports System.Drawing

Partial Class _Default
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs) Handles Calendar1.DayRender
    ' Select all dates in the past
    If e.Day.Date < System.DateTime.Today Then
      ' Disable date
      e.Day.IsSelectable = False
      ' Change color of disabled date
      e.Cell.ForeColor = Color.Gray
    End If
  End Sub
End Class

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I meant. I want to create a custom, but pretty straightforward calendar-like view of events, that I can completely control myself. It is not so much about disabling certain dates, but more about being able to show a month worth of events in a flexible way, without too many database fetches. I do appreciate your comment though.